# Facebook Graph not returning results in order

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I'm having this problem,
I'm querying the graph in order to make about 40 requests on the same query, and thought the response would be sorted in the same order that i'm making the request...

It seems it doesn't.

As I researched, Facebook processes these orders in an asynchronous way, so the resulting array won't always come in the same order that it was made...

is there a way to bypass this? or maybe give each individual request an id of some sort?

My query is as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=PageOne,PageTwo,PageThree,PageForty&fields=fan_count&access_token=XXXXXXXXX
```

As for now, I'm sometimes getting my response on the right order, but SOMETIMES not, sometimes i'd get something like:

-PageOne results

-PageFour results

-PageTwo results

-etc...

I'm doing multiple requests at once because of the API Limit, but I'm not sure if my thinking is right, could it possibly be the exact same as doing each request individually?

Comment: Well you could make the whole thing into a batch request, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests … but simply ordering the result on your end might be easier, don’t you think?

Comment: _“I'm doing multiple requests at once because of the API Limit”_ - you are not saving anything here in regard to rate limits, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting#faq

Answer (score 1):

I not sure , but I find this on doc's api facebook graph : [image: I hope this help you]